# How to add link/href to html from global constants file

Tags: html, angular, typescript, constants, global

I have a global constants file where I added a links node to it but I'm not sure how to translate that node from the constants file into the html file or possibly ts file of the html file.

**constants file**

```
 export const GlobalConstants = {   
  links: {
  classicAO: '../MicroUIs/'
 }
}
```

I added public backToClassicAO() method, but I don't know if that is correct or on the right path

**typescript**

```
 import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
 import { GlobalConstants } from 'src/app/ao-shared/global-constants';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-personalperformance-enhanced-nonqual',
    templateUrl: './personalperformance-enhanced-nonqual.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./personalperformance-enhanced-nonqual.component.scss'],
 })
export class PersonalperformanceEnhancedNonqualComponent extends AoLoadableComponent {

 constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, store: Store) {
   super(changeDetectorRef, store);
   this.store = store;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.registerModalContent();
  } 

  **public backToClassicAO(){
     window.open(GlobalConstants.links.classicAO);**
   }
 }
```

For the html I don't know if this is need but if so I want the link or href? to be for the words 'go back to the classic experience.

**html**

```
<div class="sdps-is-relative badge-example-outline sdps-p-around_medium sdps-m- 
 around_medium">  
  <div class="ao-text-header">Account Overview has a new look</div>
  You can view your retirement accounts below, or <a href="**not sure what if anything 
  goes here**">go back to the classic experience.</a>
</div>
```

In summary, I'm trying to get the constants file to connect or translate to the html to create a link for around those words.

My terminology my be off and if so I apologize. Tried to the best I can to explain. I would definitely appreciate any assistance or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u already import "GlobalConstants", then do u need create a new variable

```
_globalConstants = GlobalConstants;
```

and u can use it like this

```
<a [href]="_globalConstants.links.classicAO"
```